# Python CSV writer blank line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file, which has

```
spam
```

in it. Then, i did

```
 with open(directory, "a") as config_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(config_csv)
    writer.writerow(["something"])
    writer.writerow(["something else"])
```

I expected

```
spam
something
something else
```

Instead, I got

```
spam

"something"

"something else"
```

How do I get the thing I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you need is just what you said, there's not need for the module `csv`:

```
with open(directory, "a") as config_csv:
    config_csv.write("something\n")
    config_csv.write("something else\n")
```

Answer (score 5):

With the CSV module, use `delimiter`, `quotechar`, and `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` options to desired effect:

```
import csv
with open(file, "a", newline='') as config_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(["something"])
    writer.writerow(["something else"])
```

`file` will then contain:

```
spam
something
something else
```

Tested on Python 3.4.

Comment: how does csv.QUOTE_NONE and csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL differ?

Comment: `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` quotes fields that have delimiters or quotechar. 
(From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html): `Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields which contain special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any of the characters in lineterminator.`) 

`csv.QUOTE_NONE` quotes no fields.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers in SE did not work for me. What I did was:

```
with open('ADC.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    csv_Writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
```